# Mask format conditioned

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-wpf

Using the next code:

```
<dxe:SpinEdit Name="Spin1" IsEnabled="{Binding Data.IsEnabled}" Mask="###.######" MaskType="Numeric"/>
```

I would like to select the mask format in base of a random value. Kind of(pseudocode):

```
if (value1 == 1)
{
   Mask="###.######"
}
else
{
   Mask="###.##"
}
```

I am working in this idea (It is defined in the own grid):

```
<dxg:FormatCondition Expression="[value1] = '1'" FieldName="Spin1">
     <dxg:Format />
</dxg:FormatCondition>
```

But how I define the mask in a FormatCondition for an specific case? I Can´t figure out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it by my own...

Just sharing for if someone need it...

My idea finally was to send a param from ViewModel which define mask in spin edit.

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="value1" AllowEditing="True" Width="80">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Background="#FFFF99">
                                <dxe:SpinEdit Name="SpinEditValue1" Mask="{Binding Data.Value1Mask}" MaskType="Numeric" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate> 

        public string Value1Mask
        {
            get 
            {
                if (Designation == 1)
                {
                    return "###.##%";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "###.######";
                }
            }
        }
```